# Why does stock lose flavor in the freezer?

Tags: freezing, chicken-stock

When storing chicken stock in the freezer, a lot of sources say that it should store up to 6 month and will lose some of its flavor after that.

**What are the lost flavors and what chemical processes are responsible for this loss?**

Sources:

[How to Store Your Homemade Chicken Stock](http://www.meetpenny.com/2012/06/how-to-freeze-your-homemade-chicken-stock/)

[Food storage - how long can you keep...](https://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16776)

[How long can I leave chicken stock in the fridge?](https://ask.metafilter.com/88286/How-long-can-I-leave-chicken-stock-in-the-fridge)

[How to freeze chicken broth](https://www.myfearlesskitchen.com/how-to-freeze-chicken-broth/)

[How Long Does Chicken Broth Last?](https://www.eatsauca.com/how-long-does-chicken-broth-last/)

[How to freeze stock and other liquids](https://pamelasalzman.com/freeze-stock-liquids/)

Comment: Could you provide a source for the claim?

Comment: @canardgras Done :)